# ASP.NET APP keeps getting access denied to network share

Tags: asp.net, permissions

I have "Network Service" and myself added to the Security Permissions of the folder but I get the following error:

```
Access to the path '\\path\folder\image.gif' is denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network Share had correct Security permissions but the Share permissions were not configured properly for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Check under which user the ApplicationPool is really running: If you're running IIS 7 (and higher) this user is not the "Network Service".

Additionally you can assign a designated user to run this app-pool and grant the rights accordingly.

Comment: than you should check, whether you assigned the security permissions not only to the folder, but also for all the files in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Need to check in IIS pool that asp application is run under. Than you can assign to this pool strong identity that have acess to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Is the folder on another server? If so, you need to give the machine account for the server making the request read permissions on the remote server.